# How to modify GKE cluster master_authorized_networks_config with terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am creating a kube cluster with GKE in terraform. I am creating the cluster from two modules, a cluster module and a nodepool module. I'd like to create a module for the master_authorized_networks_config so that each time a new cidr is added to it terraform doesn't destroy the original cluster. Is this possible. This is an example of the block of code that's in my cluster module that I would like to change without destroying the whole cluster. These IP addresses are what allow acess to the cluster.

```
master_authorized_networks_config {
        cidr_blocks {
            cidr_block   = "123.456.789/32"
            display_name = "megacorp-1-nat1"
        }
        cidr_blocks {
            cidr_block   = "34.69.69.69/32"
            display_name = "megacorp-1-nat2"
        }
        cidr_blocks {
            cidr_block   = "123.456.333.333/32"
            display_name = "vpn-test"
        }
```

Adding another cidr destroys the original cluster. I don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to achieve this.
In your terraform template, write:

```
master_authorized_networks_config {
dynamic "cidr_blocks" {
  for_each = var.authorized_networks
  content {
    cidr_block = cidr_blocks.key
    display_name = cidr_blocks.value
  }
}
```

Then you can put the allowed ip ranges in a variable of type map(string).
Example:

```
authorized_networks= {
  "14.170.140.29/32": "home",
  "181.72.169.20/32": "office",
  "181.73.147.199/32": "office Wi-Fi"
}
```

Comment: This allows your authorized networks to be parameterized. Any changes to the parameter will update your cluster rather than recreate it.
On the other hand, a "hard-coded" modification of your terraform template should also be handled as an update... I have tested this on terraform 1.4.2 on darwin_arm64 with the provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.18.0